# Jquery Html Data Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, import

I've been developing a web game, with jquery doing some of the work. It was on a server, but I've moved it back to my laptop. Everything seems to work fine, except the most important function, which imports the contents of an html file.

```
$(".ReportList a").live('click', function(){
    var getreportname = $(this).text();
    $("#scroller").append("<span>The reportname is " + getreportname + "</span>");

    var usersreport = "ReportList_" + User + "";
    jQuery.get('Reports/' + getreportname + '.html', function (data) {
        $("#" + usersreport).html(data);
        $("#" + usersreport + " span").addClass("Py" + User);
        updateCount();
    });
});
```

Not sure why it stopped working. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: does the file in `Reports` exist? also, is the `Reports` folder with a capital R? case sensitivity can be environment specific

Comment: You didn't mention what **exactly** stop working.

Comment: little can go wrong assuming all the functions and variables are declared, and the path is correct.

Comment: we have missing User var and updateAccount() function... and also the path of the .html file, does it exist? can you provide a link?

Comment: @gdoron - The html file does exist, no caps problem. Is there something about the data function that won't working locally on my computer? Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Jason. The only option is that the path is broken in the new environment, Test with firebug what is the HTTP request status. come back with more info. It must be a path problem!

Comment: @gdoron - I'm not sure it's a path problem. If I add an alert before the .html(data), the alert shows up. If I mess with the path of the file, the alert doesn't show up. Also, if I add a child to the target element, it is 'erased' by the .html rewrite. It seems like it's just not extracting the data, but it seems to see the file, and plants it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need the .get() method to do what I wanted, .html() was good enough if I re-formulated the script.